# Windows 7 without powershell, how can re/install it?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

I have a stripped down version of win7 that boots from a usb drive. Is it possible to install Powershell 2 on win7 after it was, forcibly, removed from the initial install?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and installing [Windows Management Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929/en-gb), it includes (among other things) PowerShell 2.0. It's meant for Vista, XP and their respective Server versions, but might also work on a stripped down Windows 7.